# Using UTF-8 - IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find elements with a null id attribute

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My Selenium-Java project is working with 15different languages. My test will be executed based on the language that I set up before launching the browser. Using Eclipse for writing code.

Since the text varies, Based on the text, I'm identifying the element and entering text in the text field. For e.g, For UK it is 'City', but for Italy, it is 'Città'.
Note: I'm unable to use straight away with the locator, because the text/Questionnaire will have different locations between these languages.

And there is a must that the file encoding I should use is UTF-8.

When I execute it, it errors as 'IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find elements with a null id attribute.' Please correct me where I'm wrong.

Below class is to access the Test Data to be entered in the question field.

```
public class GetQuestionLocator {
public static String getLocator(String questionname) {
String locatorvalue = null;
switch (questionname) {
//Building Information Questions
  case "Site name": //UK
  case "Name des Standorts":  //Germany, Austria
  case "Building #":  //Italy
  case "Naam locatie": //nld
  case "Kohteen nimi": //Finland
  case "Nombre de la instalación":  //Spain, Andorra, Marvi
  case "Platsnamn":  //Sweden
  case "Nome da instalação":  //Portugal
  case "Stedets navn":  //Denmark
    locatorvalue = AssessmentPageData.BuildingDescription;
    break;
  case "Street address": //UK
  case "Straße": //Germany, Austria
  case "Edificio": //Italy
  case "Straatnaam": //nld
  case "Katuosoite": //Finland
  case "Dirección":  //Spain, Andorra, Marvi
  case "Gatuadress":  //Sweden
  case "Direcção":  //Portugal
  case "Vejnavn":  //Denmark
    locatorvalue = AssessmentPageData.BuildingAddress;
    break;
  case "City": //UK
  case "Ort":  //Germany, Austria
  case "Città":  //Italy
  case "Plaats": //nld
  case "Kaupunki": //Finland
  case "Ciudad":  //Spain, Andorra, Marvi
  case "Stad":  //Sweden
  case "Cidade":  //Portugal
  case "By":  //Denmark
    locatorvalue = AssessmentPageData.BuildingCity;
    break;
}
```

Below is how I map the Excel data and locators.

```
public void provideBuildingDetails(String FL) throws InterruptedException {
        String SiteName = null;
        String StreetAddress = null;
        String City = null;
        String PostalCode = null;
        String Country = null;
        String BuildingDescription = null;
        String BuildingAddress = null;
        String BuildingCity = null;
        String BuildingPostalCode = null;
        String BuildingCountry = null;
        switch (FL) {
        case "UK":
            SiteName = Xls_Reader.getData("UKBuildingQuestions", "BuildingInformationQuestions", "SiteName");
            StreetAddress = Xls_Reader.getData("UKBuildingQuestions", "BuildingInformationQuestions","StreetAddress");
            City = Xls_Reader.getData("UKBuildingQuestions", "BuildingInformationQuestions", "City");
            PostalCode = Xls_Reader.getData("UKBuildingQuestions", "BuildingInformationQuestions", "PostalCode");
            Country = Xls_Reader.getData("UKBuildingQuestions", "BuildingInformationQuestions", "Country");
            BuildingDescription = Xls_Reader.getData("UKBuildingQuestions", "ProvideBuildingDetails","BuildingDescription");
            BuildingAddress = Xls_Reader.getData("UKBuildingQuestions", "ProvideBuildingDetails","BuildingAddress");
            BuildingCity = Xls_Reader.getData("UKBuildingQuestions", "ProvideBuildingDetails", "BuildingCity");
            BuildingPostalCode = Xls_Reader.getData("UKBuildingQuestions", "ProvideBuildingDetails","BuildingPostalCode");
            BuildingCountry = Xls_Reader.getData("UKBuildingQuestions", "ProvideBuildingDetails","BuildingCountry");
            break;

        case "Italy":
            SiteName = Xls_Reader.getData("ItalyBuildingQuestions", "BuildingInformationQuestions", "SiteName");
            StreetAddress = Xls_Reader.getData("ItalyBuildingQuestions", "BuildingInformationQuestions","StreetAddress");
            City = Xls_Reader.getData("ItalyBuildingQuestions", "BuildingInformationQuestions", "City");
            PostalCode = Xls_Reader.getData("ItalyBuildingQuestions", "BuildingInformationQuestions", "PostalCode");
            Country = Xls_Reader.getData("ItalyBuildingQuestions", "BuildingInformationQuestions", "Country");
            BuildingDescription = Xls_Reader.getData("ItalyBuildingQuestions", "ProvideBuildingDetails","BuildingDescription");
            BuildingAddress = Xls_Reader.getData("ItalyBuildingQuestions", "ProvideBuildingDetails","BuildingAddress");
            BuildingCity = Xls_Reader.getData("ItalyBuildingQuestions", "ProvideBuildingDetails", "BuildingCity");
            BuildingPostalCode = Xls_Reader.getData("ItalyBuildingQuestions", "ProvideBuildingDetails","BuildingPostalCode");
            BuildingCountry = Xls_Reader.getData("ItalyBuildingQuestions", "ProvideBuildingDetails","BuildingCountry");
            break;
            }
        ClickOnElement("id", AssessmentPageData.BuildingQuestionGroupInfo);
        String locator = GetQuestionLocator.getLocator(SiteName);
        EnterValuesByIndex("id", locator, BuildingDescription, 1);
        locator = GetQuestionLocator.getLocator(StreetAddress);
        EnterValuesByIndex("id", locator, BuildingAddress, 1);
        locator = GetQuestionLocator.getLocator(City);
        EnterValuesByIndex("id", locator, BuildingCity, 1);
        locator = GetQuestionLocator.getLocator(PostalCode);
        EnterValuesByIndex("id", locator, BuildingPostalCode, 1);
        locator = GetQuestionLocator.getLocator(Country);
        EnterValuesByIndex("id", locator, BuildingCountry, 1);
    }
```

In the Excel for Italy,
[image]

Exception is as shown below,
[image]

Comment: You need to post your HTML code snippet. That will help us to help you for building locator like xpath for you

Comment: I have updated with HTML script, Please check.

Comment: Please post complete exception and also the line of which the exception occurs

Comment: Updated the Exception. Im executing the code from Git using command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is rectified by the following steps,

1. Goto Eclipse->Window->Preferences->editor->Click TextEditor
2. Click Spelling
3. Choose Other under Encoding section and select UTF-8 from the dropdown.
4. Click Apply
5. Restart Eclipse